# How to format data json before returning?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I use `mongodb aggregation` with example data:

```
{
"name": "John wire",
"city": "New York"
},
{
"name": "mike jansen",
"city": "Dubai"
}

...etc
```

and my return aggregation code is:

```
], function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    logger.error(req.method + ": " + req.originalUrl + ", message: " + err.message)
    next(createError.InternalServerError())
  }
    
  res.send(result); //this line
});
```

and I have a function to return field `name` to `capitalize` every first word:

```
function titleCase(str) {
    var splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
        // You do not need to check if i is larger than splitStr length, as your for does that for you
        // Assign it back to the array
        splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);     
    }
    // Directly return the joined string
    return splitStr.join(' '); 
  }
```

Example: John wire -> John Wire

How can I format the `result.name` data before it's returning?

Thank you.

Comment: is `titleCase` function working fine ?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you want: `const formatted = result.map(({ name, city }) => ({ name: titleCase(name), city })); res.send(formatted);`

Comment: What's the problem you are having? Your titleCase function is work as the way you wanted to.

Comment: @Corey thanks, that i what i want. But, how can i just type name in result.map? Because actually i have many field on that data.

Comment: @Corey so i shouldnt add one by one field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spread operator introduced with ES6:

```
result.map(o => ({ ...o, name: titleCase(o.name)}));
```

ES5:

```
result.map(o => Object.assign(o, {name: titleCase(o.name)}));
```